# Inserting data into MySql

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with data I would like to use to populate a variety of tables in MySql. To ensure that business logic is adhered to, I have developed a series of stored procedures. Each row can call one or more of these procedures - depending on the contents.

I have thought of two possible solutions - Either

a) Write a PHP script to do it;

or

b) Write an Excel Macro to do it.

It must be noted that the data is still in the stage of possibly being edited before going live.

So my question is, what is the best solution? Any possible advantages/disadvantages with either one? Any possible pitfalls? Are there any other possible solutions?

Comment: Are users running this, if so, will they be running it from Excel?

Comment: The idea is to collect/edit the data in an Ecel spreadsheet during the development phase. This data is then imported into the MySql up until the thing goes live. I can see advantages in bother methods. just wondering if anybody else has face a fimilar situation and would like to learn from their experiences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with PHP if you populate the DB with data from Excel. I recommend http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ for data manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a php script. With it you can have the logic externalized and easily reuse it later.

There are a lot of classes/libraries
([PHP excel reader for example](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/))
that you can use to parse the spreadsheet, thus the script can contain only content-related logic.